# Drawing a triangle using mouse clicks in java graphics

Tags: java, graphics, mouse

this is my code. It worked for drawing a circle but I am having troubles drawing a triangle now.. A triangle should appear using mouse clicks but it is showing a triangle immediately after running the application. Please help. Thanks.

```
    package mouse;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.awt.geom.*;

public class triangle extends JFrame implements ActionListener, MouseListener {
    int xx[]= {20, 50, 80};
    int yy[]= {80, 30, 80};



    public triangle () {
        setSize(2000,2000);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //TODO code application logic here
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                   triangle frame = new triangle();
                   frame.setVisible(true);
              }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

    }

    public void drawPolygon(int x, int y, int i)
    {
        Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawPolygon(xx, yy, 3);

    }

    int x, y;

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();

        repaint();
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        drawPolygon(x, y, 3);
    }



    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}``
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you override the paint method and therefore the drawPolygon method is already called in the initial painting of the JFrame.

For the effect you want to have you should avoid overriding the paint method and only use the drawPolygon method when the MouseListener is invoked.

This should look like this:

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();

    drawPolygon(x,y,3);

    repaint();
}
```

In order to paint the triangle where you click with the mouse you need to add the current position to the original triangle coordinates like this:

```
public void drawPolygon(int x, int y, int i)
{
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    int[] drawx = {xx[0]+x,xx[1]+x,xx[2]+x};
    int[] drawy = {yy[0]+y,yy[1]+y,yy[2]+y};

    g.drawPolygon(drawx, drawy, i);

}
```

I hope this answers you question.

Some general remarks on programming:
You should definitely include a

```
               frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

otherwise you program won't terminate on closing the frame and keep on running.

It would also help the readability of your code if you avoid having everything in one class and split your code into several classes. 
The [MVC model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is something that is a very good general guideline for designing class structures.